# How to resolve SIM update error InvalidDeploymentException?

Tags: sim

Invalid deployment exception on updating SIM 1.3 to SIM 1.4. How to resolve this?

```
ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [11/13/2018 3:14:26 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (SubscriptionSemanticValidation)
    - The deployment identity at the deployment provider is not the same as the original deployment identity.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.FollowDeploymentProviderUri(SubscriptionStore subStore, AssemblyManifest& deployment, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

New error on a fresh installation of SIM1.5

```
ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [11/13/2018 4:12:02 PM] System.Deployment.Application.DeploymentDownloadException (Unknown subtype)
        - Downloading http://dl.sitecore.net/updater/sim/Application Files/SIM.Tool.1.5.0.179/Sitecore.Diagnostics.Net.dll did not succeed.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            at System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
            at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.WebException
        - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
            at System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.IO.IOException
        - Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
            at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
        - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        - Source: System
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

Comment: Delete (uninstall) SIM and download the new version

Comment: @MarkCassidy - tried installing SIM 1.5 and noticed a new error where it fails to download Sitecore.Diagnostics.Net.dll for some reason. Though Im able to install SIM 1.5 QA version without any issues.

Comment: I only use the QA version